# Will_paginate customize links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, will-paginate

I'm doing an ajax call for sorting data. But for pagination links its just a link and not ajax call.

Now the problem is when I sort data the pagination link generated is in this format:

```
/homes/index.js?page=2&amp;sort_name=origin_address&amp;sort_type=desc
```

The link I want it to generate is:

/homes/index?page=2&sort_name=origin_address&sort_type=desc

I'm doing this:

```
will_paginate(object, params: { controller: "homes", action: "index", status: params[:status] }, previous_label: '<ul><div class="prev" aria-hidden="true"></div>'.html_safe, next_label: '<div class="next" aria-hidden="true"></div></ul>'.html_safe)
```

But its not working.

Comment: how about using parameterize ?So at the controller level...you can get the values easily...

Comment: Can you show a sample code?